# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Productionserver'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

```
this.route.data.subscribe((data:Data)=>{
    this.servers = data['server'];

console.log(this.servers);
  
  });
```

The above code outputs like this to console

```
{id: 1, name: "Productionserver", status: "online"}
```

How to display this in view.

I tried like this but its not working

```
<div *ngFor="let server of servers">
{{server.id}}{{server.name}}{{server.status}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the error message it means `servers` isn't an array so you can't iterate on it with `*ngFor` as it's an object. It isn't data about several server but about a single server.

You should change the wording from *servers* to *server* to avoid confusion (as stated into you sample : `data['server]`.

Then just use your previous template sample without the `*ngFor` part :

```
{{server.id}}{{server.name}}{{server.status}}
```